# Using "to make " vs. "that it makes"

Tags: grammar

Can I use the following construction :

> Users of Win System will get the update **that it make** the Web
>   applications work faster.

Instead of the following phrase:

> Users of Win System will get the update **to make** the Web applications
>   work faster.

Comment: The first version is syntactic nonsense. The second is okay except you don't want the article in *make Web applications work faster*. But as it stands this question is Off Topic proofreading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence

> Users of Win System will get the update that *it make* the Web applications work faster.

is not correct.

Alternatives might be

> Users of Win System will get the update that *makes* the Web applications work faster.

or

> Users of Win System will get the update that *will* make the Web applications work faster.

You are mixing the plurality of your subject with its verb.